# Why can’t I enable True Tone on my iPhone 11 anymore?

Tags: iphone, ios, display

I noticed today that True Tone has disappeared from my iPhone 11 settings. Even in the control center I can't find it anymore. I rebooted it but it didn't come back.

Any idea on why it's gone and how I can get it back ?

[image: Screenshot of the Settings]

Comment: Did you have the screen replaced?  Is invert colors or smart invert turned on?

Comment: No, I bought the phone a month ago, and it’s turned off

Comment: What iOS version are you running?  I notice your screenshot doesn't show the setting for light/dark mode.  Also, make sure your device isn't jailbroken.

Comment: It’s not jailbroken and I’m on iOS 13.3.1. It’s not on the screenshot because it’s upper but I have the light/dark mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just came back from the Apple Store and they found the problem: my Ambient Light sensor was faulty and they changed it for free. Thanks anyway for your help !